# Core OOPS : Encapsulation

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation, concept

Yesterday in an Interview I was asked
**How Does Encapsulation works internally ?**
I was really confused because as per me Encapsulation is simply
`"The state of a class should only be accessed through its public interface."`
but when it comes to internal working I ran out of words.So if anyone can explain that it would be so helpful.

Comment: Could you not ask for clarification? Sounds like a silly question. Although what encapsulation really is is hiding as much data as you can, each individual bit of data exposed by a public interface weakens encapsulation.

Comment: You should have ask your interviewer for some more details. How "internal" you had to go - did he expect you to explain byte-code details? With how the question is stated right now we're not really able to answer it.

Comment: I asked him for more clarification on this but I guess he was offended and did not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with commenters that asking for clarifications is a good idea - good questions can be even better than good answers, and allow you to ensure that you are actually answering what they think that they are asking.

In this case, I assume that they wanted you to explain **how Java ensures that programmers do not violate encapsulation**. This involves

- built-in syntax and semantics for marking fields / methods as public, private, protected, or package-protected.
- compiler checks to ensure that these are not violated
- (external) tools available to detect code smells relating to encapsulation, such as calls to overridable methods from within a constructor.
- (somewhat more far-fetched) no direct access to program memory, making, for example, reinterpret-casts such as found in C / C++ unavailable in Java; this also preserves encapsulation.

You could have ensured that this is what they wanted by asking **"are you referring to how Java ensures that programmers do not violate encapsulation, that is, that they do not access the state of objects except through their public interface?"**

Additional answers come to mind:

- use of meaningful comments, easily accessible via JavaDoc both in-IDE and as browsable documentation, that allow programmers to understand how classes are meant to be used and composed.
- strong coding conventions that enforce encapsulation, such as setting fields to the most restrictive access possible, and only making public those parts that should actually be public.

Comment: Ultimately I did answer this only, that how java handles encapsulation by using access modifiers and blah blah but he was like I want to know internal working. So I dig in lots of blog ,looked in books and finally decided to put this on stackoverflow to get some expert comments, turns out I explained him exactly what Encapsulation is and How java ensures its implementation.

Comment: Internal-wise, you can explain what a compiler does, the fact that the Java compiler generates an abstract syntax tree (AST) that contains field, class and method access descriptors (generating errors if invalid access is detected at compile-time), and that they are further preserved in the bytecode to be checked at runtime, although they can be modified through introspection